# Favicon not displayed in create react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, favicon

It is default setup in create-react-app application that I am using. But the favicon is not displayed. Not even the react favicon that comes with create-react-app. I can see the favicon link in the chrome's inspect tab. Also the icon gets loaded in localhost too for the link "http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico"

Following link is present in the index.html as well

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
```

What am I doing wrong for it to not be displayed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That issues happened for me too , what i did was i just went to this [site](https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-ico) .. from there i created my .ico image and gave my absolute path of that .ico image . 
Ex :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/myfavicon.ico">
```

Comment: I had reset my index.html file to last best previous version. There isn't much difference but it seems to be working fine now. If you give an absolute path, it should be changed again when build is made separately, right ?